# Anaconda: How to safely remove duplicate packages

Tags: python, anaconda

I have an Anaconda virtual environment in which I have a lot of Python packages installed multiple times, often in different versions, for example:

```
$ conda list
...
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py35_0  
sip                       4.18                     py35_0  
six                       1.10.0                    <pip>
six                       1.11.0                    <pip>
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0  
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py35_0  
sockjs-tornado            1.0.3                    py35_0  
sphinx                    1.5.4                    py35_0  
spyder                    3.1.3                    py35_0  
sqlalchemy                1.1.9                    py35_0  
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
statsmodels               0.8.0               np111py35_0  
sympy                     1.0                      py35_0  
tensorflow-gpu            1.3.0                     <pip>
tensorflow-gpu            1.0.1                     <pip>
tensorflow-tensorboard    0.1.6                     <pip>
terminado                 0.6                      py35_0  
testpath                  0.3                      py35_0  
Theano                    0.9.0                     <pip>
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
toolz                     0.8.2                    py35_0  
tornado                   4.4.2                    py35_0  
tqdm                      4.11.2                    <pip>
tqdm                      4.15.0                   py35_0  
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py35_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py35_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py35_0  
werkzeug                  0.12.1                   py35_0  
Werkzeug                  0.12.2                    <pip>
wheel                     0.29.0                    <pip>
wheel                     0.30.0                    <pip>
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0  
...
```

I don't know how I got to this state, but how can I safely get rid of the duplicate packages?

Also, if a program imports the `six` package, how does Python determine which version to import?

**EDIT:**
I know now where the problem came from. I probably installed some packages using `pip`'s `--ignore-installed` option. Am I fine with all the duplicates being installed like this or should I get rid of them?

Comment: Uninstall all and re-install?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need specific version of any one of those, then I would try `conda update conda` which should remove all the old packages, install the newest versions, and set the newest versions as default. Otherwise, you can always use `conda remove <pkg-name>` to remove all the copies and `conda install <pkg-name>` to install the latest version and replace the old ones. You can also use `pip install <pkg-name>==<version>` to install a specific version (for example, `pip install keras==1.2`). This [link](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/2988) is also helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Is there no way to uninstall a specific version of a package? I tried `pip uninstall Werkzeug==0.12.2`, but it resulted in `Uninstalling Werkzeug-0.14.1: ...`

Comment: There might be a way, but I personally would uninstall all the versions and then install the one I need (I don't like the mess created by ignore-installed). Note that if you need different versions, the right way is to make a new environment for each version and NOT install them side-by-side.

Answer (score 4):

For begginers, this tutorial might be useful

```
conda clean --all
```

https://youtu.be/GNd_em2IzW4

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. As Mehdi suggested, I found it best to make a new conda environment. See [this link](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) for details. You can simply put the requirements in a yaml file like this:

```
name: my_name

dependencies:
  - numpy
  - python=3.6.0=0
  - pandas
  - ipython
  - matplotlib
  - pip:
    - click==6.6
    - keras==1.2
```

and then run the following (say the file above is saved as env.yaml):

```
conda env create -n my_name -f env.yml
source activate my_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, where I wanted to remove all of the packages I installed through `pip` in a conda environment. You can do it with this one-liner:

```sh
conda list | grep '<pip>' | tr -s [:blank:] | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -d'\n' pip uninstall -y
```

If you're on macOS, you'll need to `brew install findutils` and change `xargs` to `gxargs`.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda clean
```

some command arguments

```
--lock, --tarballs, --index-cache, --packages, --source-cache, --all
```

reference:- 
https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-clean.html